# How to install minikube and docker in Windows 10?

Tags: docker, hyper-v, minikube

I want to work on minikube . I installed it successfully but I learned that in Windows 10 , I need to disable Hyper-v . 
Now , when I try to install docker , it needs Hyper-v enabled .

I need both for work .

Please suggest a way to make this happen .

Appreciate your help . :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a new virtual switch in Hyper-V Manager for Minikube.

1. Open the Hyper-V Manager (simple Windows search will find it)
2. Select 'Virtual Switch Manager'
3. Select 'New virtual network switch' and choose network type 'External'
4. Create the virtual switch (take note of the name you save it with)
5. Then when starting up minikube you can do the following: `minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "<your switch name>"`

Approach taken from the following Medium article: https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c

Comment: I was able to install it . But minikube stop didn't work . It hangs .

Comment: They have an open bug on that it seems: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2914  is that the same  as you  are experiencing?

Comment: If you *still* experience problems after this (like I did), then do a
```minikube delete```
prior to the
```minikube start --vm-driver=hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch=ExternalSwitch```

Answer (score 3):

@bkr you don't have to turn off Hyper-V to use minikube.

Scenarios are like this:

1) Use Docker, and minikube with Hyper-V (you will find instruction in an answer above) 
Enable Hyper-V, install Docker, use minikube with arguments `minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "<created Hyper-V switch name>"`
In the same time you will be able to interact with Docker in normal way. Use kubectl/minikube commands for your Kubernetes cluster and Docker commands for Docker.
2) [Use VirtualBox for Kubernetes and Docker toolbox for Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600524/is-it-possible-to-run-minikube-with-virtualbox-on-windows-10-along-with-docker/52611412#52611412) 
`minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox`

3) Use [Docker for Windows](https://blog.docker.com/2018/01/docker-windows-desktop-now-kubernetes/) and [Kubernetes in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093457/how-to-run-kubernetes-and-docker-at-the-same-time-on-windows-10-pro/53121119#53121119)