# After configuring for docker, minikube doesn't run anymore

Tags: kubernetes, hyper-v, minikube, docker-desktop

I user minikube on windows. It was working perfectly, but my "docker-for-desktop" wasn't.

After running the command `BCDEDIT /Set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype auto` my Docker app started to work but everytime I try to start my minikube VM it shows me an error about "VBOX_VERRR_VMW_NO_VMX".

When i run the `BCDEDIT /Set {current} hypervisorlaunchtype off` minikube works again, but DOcker doesn't. And I docker working for build the docker images, and the minikube for hosting them.

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow official guides for Docker for Windows and Minikube? I wrote some answers about particular scenarios with Windows, Docker for Windows and minikube. Try reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53431590/9892073) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600524/is-it-possible-to-run-minikube-with-virtualbox-on-windows-10-along-with-docker/52611412#52611412). They should be enough to solve the problems.

If you still have issues try to describe what steps you have made that led you to the error.

Comment: It seems that now it's working on running both through Hyper-V.Thanks a lot man, I didn't know about the differences between HyperV and VirtualBox :P

Comment: Glad I could help. I suspected you want to use two virtualization software and decided to provide the all scenarios explanation.