# How do I access minikube docker daemon on Windows?

Tags: docker, minikube

I installed minikube and now I want to create my docker containers, but how do I run the docker commands?  I tried the following from command prompt

[image]

But it does not recognize docker as a command.

Also I tried from PowerShell with the same result, docker not recognized.

I currently only have minikube installed on my workstation because I was given the impression from comments to a previous question that I did not need Docker Desktop (see [Unable to connect to running docker containers (minikube docker daemon)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59989739/unable-to-connect-to-running-docker-containers-minikube-docker-daemon))

Comment: How did you get your Minikube installed?

Comment: @OhHiMark just followed the instructions for using the installer executable https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/

Answer (score 1):

In [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53429687/how-to-install-minikube-and-docker-in-windows-10) there is an answer that will show you 3 ways how to make Minikube and Docker work on Windows:

> Scenarios are like this:
>
> 1) Use Docker, and minikube with Hyper-V (you will find instruction in
>   an answer above)  Enable Hyper-V, install Docker, use minikube with
>   arguments `minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch
>   "<created Hyper-V switch name>"` In the same time you will be able to
>   interact with Docker in normal way. Use kubectl/minikube commands for
>   your Kubernetes cluster and Docker commands for Docker.   2) [Use
>   VirtualBox for Kubernetes and Docker toolbox for Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52600524/is-it-possible-to-run-minikube-with-virtualbox-on-windows-10-along-with-docker/52611412#52611412)  `minikube
>   start --vm-driver=virtualbox`
>
> 3) Use [Docker for Windows](https://blog.docker.com/2018/01/docker-windows-desktop-now-kubernetes/) and [Kubernetes in Docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53093457/how-to-run-kubernetes-and-docker-at-the-same-time-on-windows-10-pro/53121119#53121119)

I believe this will solve your issue. Please, let me know if that helped.